# java NIO, selectedKeys, and channels for STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR

Tags: java, nio

I have a program that pipes stdout, stderr, and stdin through Pipe.SourceChannel's to/from BytesBuffers.

The program registers each channel with a selector.

The program in a loop periodically iterates through each key in the set of selectedKeys, which correspond to stdout, stderr, and stdin.  For each key, it determines if the key is valid, and readable or writable, and if so, it conducts the corresponding IO operation to/from a ByteBuffer

My question is what can I assume about the set of initially selected keys (corresponding to stdin , stdout , stderr) when the program begins.

Will the key for stdin be always be the first key to be ready, valid and readable?
Could the key for stdout be ready, valid and readable *before* stdin?

I ask because my programs behavior is having random IO behavior, and I'm guessing that my assumptions about initial key set membership are wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Asked again here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014570/java-nio-and-end-of-stream-for-stdin-stdout-stderr

Comment: @Peter, my two questions were meant to be different, and I probably didn't express them clearly.  The question here is about the **order** in which channels become readable/writable.  The question that you linked to is about whether channels for stdin/stdout/stderr can be opened or closed multiple times during a program's execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channels are readable when there is data that can be read without blocking.

Channels are writable *except* when there is no room in their kernel socket send buffers, which only happens if they are writing faster than the reader is reading.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  My question is more about the order in which channels for stdin, stdout, and stderr become readable/writable, when the program initially starts up.  From your comment "Channels are readable when there is data that can be read without blocking.", it seems that there is no guarantee about the in order in which data for stdout or stderr can be read without blocking; stdout could be readable before stderr or vice versa.  I hope I understand this correctly.

Comment: Also re: "Channels are readable when there is data that can be read without blocking.", what if stdout/stdin/stderr are empty?  I've found that even if the streams are empty from the start of program execution, the channel itself can be readable.  So it doesn't seem that the has to be data there to be readable?

Comment: @morfys I have never found that. 'Readable' in `select()` terms is defined as above: you can either read data or an EOS from the channel. If `select()` tells you the channel is readable and a `read()` immediately returns zero there is something seriously wrong somewhere, most likely with your code.

Comment: Just to clarify, I meant that the channel is readable, and read() immediately return -1 for EOS.  Is this behavior normal?

Comment: @morfys Of course. At which point you should close th channel so it doesn't keep happening.