# java nio and end of stream for stdin, stdout, stderr

Tags: java, nio

I have a program A that receives stdout of another program B in a ByteBuffer through a Pipe.SourceChannel.

The program will read from the ByteBuffer for stdout until it reaches the end of stream (that is, until ByteBuffer's read() return -1).

Can stdout of program B open and close multiple times in a program's execution?  That is, is it possible that read() return -1, but later program B has additional stdout, in which case program A should do another read() of the ByteBuffer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have to have threads for each channel any way, I dont see the point of adding an NIO layer in front of it.  I would just process the input or output as you get it or generate it. All the reasons you might use NIO dont appear to apply in this situation.

Comment: @Peter, I use **direct** ByteBuffers from NIO for receiving stdout and writing stdin from program A to program B.  My (perhaps faulty?) reasoning is that IO should be faster this way.

Comment: NIO is faster because it removes some of the layers which are required for IO. In your case, you can't avoid the IO layer and adding an NIO layer is going to make it significantly slower and more complex. i.e. NIO is faster because it a thinner layer, if more complicated to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Linux, you can use NIO for stdin, stdout and stderr, because they are tied to certain character devices, which can be accessed as files. To do this you can open `/proc/self/fd/0`, `1` or `2` respectively.  This doesn't work for all stream types, or on non-Unix systems, but it may be an option.

Once a stream has closed, it is not possible to reopen it, unless it was a file and you were able to obtain the file name.

Comment: What nio class should I use to open /proc/self/fd/0 ?

Comment: Any file NIO can be used, however you can only memory map real files.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.  stdout, stderr, and stdin are all "special" streams.  you can't close them and re-open them later.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Can the operating system open and close stdout, stderr, or stdin streams (e.g. if program B interweaves reading stdin with writing to stdout)?  If not, then if Pipe.SourceChannel's read() return -1, I can assume all input/output has been read from the stream?

Comment: I am thinking about the case where program B pipes it's output to the stdin of program A.  Couldn't program B open and close two streams one after the other to the stdin of program A? In that case, a read() on the channel could return -1 twice, right?

Comment: @morfys No, it can't do that. There is no API for that action of process B.